# How to make clickable image in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, scrollview, items

I have a scroll view and it give images from database and image view in scroll view create dynamically.I want to when select one of images it display on another activity or bigger.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private DatabaseH db;
private Bitmap[] ax;
ImageView im;
int i;
String table="main";
String noeDastor="کار با فایل";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DatabaseH(this);
    db.useable();
    refresher();
    LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    for ( i = 0; i < ax.length; i++) {
    im=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    im.setImageBitmap(ax[i]);
    yourLayout.addView(im,700,500);

}
    OnClickListener on=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("integer", i);
            intent.putExtra("table", table);
            intent.putExtra("noeDastor", noeDastor);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void refresher(){
    db.open();
    int save = db.shomaresh_field(table,noeDastor);
    ax = new Bitmap[save];

    for (int i = 0; i <save; i++) {
        ax[i] = db.retrive(table,noeDastor,i);  
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and set orientation horizontal like this :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView rvSlide = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvSlide);
rvSlide.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Use ImageView as a RecyclerView item and in adapter handle the `onClickListner` on ImageView then you get what you want.

Comment: RecyclerView is not in eclipse.is that have a special lib??

Comment: @shayan talaei yes you need to use Android Support Library v7 for Recycler. Which is available at your sdk folder. You just need to import it in eclipse and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop with every add view you should set imageView Id like 0,1,2,etc. as you like

```
imageView.setId(i);
```

then you get id by using

```
imageView.getId();
```

to be use and find which clicked has been performed but in your imageView.onClickListener callback

Comment: tnx but i got a little confuse.how to use an id that i get from     getId()

Comment: i want to choose an image then it go to another activity.how can do this??

Comment: because every view has method to setId(), and getId(), which is really beneficial of dynamic view creation and give and id as identifier. I have already used the same concept over your type situation.